# how to use a defined view in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a view, model and store :

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.TripList', {
    fullscreen: true,
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'TripListView',
    store: 'TripStore',
    displayField: 'text'

});

Ext.define('myApp.model.Trip', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'Name', type: 'auto' }

        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('myApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'MyAccountant.view.TripList'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                title: 'Trip List',
                iconCls: 'list',
                scrollable: true,
                xtype: 'TripListView'
                //view: 'MyAccountant.view.TripList'
            }

        ]
    }
});
```

I want to display a nestedList.

So how can I use a defined view (TripList) inside the Main view?

Thanks

```
**Update:**
```

Here is the store code:

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.Trips', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    defaultRootProperty: 'Name',
    requires: ['myApp.model.Trip'],
    config: {
        model: 'myApp.model.Trip',
        storeId: 'TripStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        data: [
            { Name: 'Thailand Trip', Date: '2014.03.03', Friends: 'irene@gmail.com, franva008@gmail.com', Description: 'We will explore the hustle and bustle markets in the acient country.' },
            { Name: 'Malysia Trip', Date: '2014.03.03', Friends: 'irene@gmail.com, franva008@gmail.com', Description: 'We will explore the hustle and bustle markets in the acient country.' },
            { Name: 'U.S.A. Trip', Date: '2014.03.03', Friends: 'irene@gmail.com, franva008@gmail.com', Description: 'We will explore the hustle and bustle markets in the acient country.' },
            { Name: 'The Great China Trip', Date: '2014.03.03', Friends: 'irene@gmail.com, franva008@gmail.com', Description: 'We will explore the hustle and bustle markets in the acient country.' }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an instance of it as any other view or component.

Either by doing this...

```
items: [
   Ext.create('myApp.view.TripList')
]
```

Or use it's alias (xtype)...

```
items:[
   {
      xtype: 'TripListView',
      ....
   }
]
```

**EDIT**

Here's a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3hg

And here's the code...

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Trip', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [{
            name: 'Name',
            type: 'auto'
        }, {
            name: 'Date',
            type: 'auto'
        }, {
            name: 'Friends',
            type: 'auto'
        }, {
            name: 'Description',
            type: 'auto'
        }

        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.store.Trips', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    defaultRootProperty: 'Name',
    requires: ['MyApp.model.Trip'],
    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.Trip',
        storeId: 'TripStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        data: [{
            Name: 'Thailand Trip',
            Date: '2014.03.03',
            Friends: 'irene@gmail.com, franva008@gmail.com',
            Description: 'We will explore the hustle and bustle markets in the acient country.'
        }, {
            Name: 'Malysia Trip',
            Date: '2014.03.03',
            Friends: 'irene@gmail.com, franva008@gmail.com',
            Description: 'We will explore the hustle and bustle markets in the acient country.'
        }, {
            Name: 'U.S.A. Trip',
            Date: '2014.03.03',
            Friends: 'irene@gmail.com, franva008@gmail.com',
            Description: 'We will explore the hustle and bustle markets in the acient country.'
        }, {
            Name: 'The Great China Trip',
            Date: '2014.03.03',
            Friends: 'irene@gmail.com, franva008@gmail.com',
            Description: 'We will explore the hustle and bustle markets in the acient country.'
        }]
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.TripList', {
    requires: ['MyApp.store.Trips'],
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'TripListView',
    config:{
        itemTpl: '{Name}',
        fullscreen:true,
        store: Ext.create('MyApp.store.Trips').load()        
    }


});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: ['Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.Video', 'Ext.dataview.List', 'Ext.XTemplate', 'MyAccountant.view.TripList'],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [{
            title: 'Trip List',
            iconCls: 'list',
            layout:'fit',
            items: [
                Ext.create('MyApp.view.TripList',{
                    width:'100%'
                })
            ]
        }, {
            title: 'Welcome',
            iconCls: 'home',

            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Welcome to Sencha Touch 2'
            },

            html: ["You've just generated a new Sencha Touch 2 project. What you're looking at right now is the ", "contents of <a target='_blank' href=\"app/view/Main.js\">app/view/Main.js</a> - edit that file ", "and refresh to change what's rendered here."].join("")
        }]
    }
});

/*
    This file is generated and updated by Sencha Cmd. You can edit this file as
    needed for your application, but these edits will have to be merged by
    Sencha Cmd when it performs code generation tasks such as generating new
    models, controllers or views and when running "sencha app upgrade".

    Ideally changes to this file would be limited and most work would be done
    in other places (such as Controllers). If Sencha Cmd cannot merge your
    changes and its generated code, it will produce a "merge conflict" that you
    will need to resolve manually.
*/

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',


    controolers: ['MyApp.controller.Main'],

    views: ['Main', 'MyApp.view.TripList'],


    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element


        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main'));
    },

    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm("Application Update", "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",

        function(buttonId) {
            if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: hi lascort, thx to your reply. However, I got an error:  Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#doAdd] Adding a card to a tab container without specifying any tab configuration .  After followed your way.

Comment: answered in my edit, and by the way, you should have mentioned that error in your post and probably it's title, the title is kinda misleading

Comment: Hi, I didn't have that error in my original code as I had the title, iconCls etc. in my original code.

Comment: Oh ok, just got it, try the last bit I suggested, the edit part

Comment: hi lascort, it doesn't solve my problem. I still can't see any items in the list view. Those items I mentioned are in my store. Please see my update. thx :)

Comment: ok so there could be and error in your list, try with a regular component first, for example a panel with a title and check if that works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52421/discussion-between-lascort-and-franva)

Comment: hi lascort, thank you so much for your help. However, after followed exactly same as yours, I still can't make it work. Please have a look at my fiddle:    https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=5ns#fiddle/5ns

Comment: hi lascort, 
I just did inspection of the DOM an found that the data is actually loaded but the view just doesn't show